# Full gradient background with svg shape blended on top

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a full gradient background, the thing is that I also need a clipping kind of mask, that gives a shape on top of the background color, what I ended up doing was using an SVG to make the shape and "cut" the top part of the background giving the shape that I wanted.

The problem now is that I don't know how to blend the colors to match, what I tried was to set the SVG color to match the beginning color of the gradient of the background, but doesn't work, because if you make the high  of the screen bigger, the colors start to change, so I cannot make it consistent.

This is what I have so far:

```css
body {
            /* Keep the inherited background full size. */
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
          padding-left:100px;
          padding-right:100px;
        }

.glass {
            height: 100vh;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            background: inherit;
            overflow: hidden;
            flex-grow: 100;
            background: rgb(255,235,59);
            background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,235,59,1) 0%, rgba(253,216,53,1) 54%, rgba(249,168,37,1) 100%);

        }

svg {
            background: white;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }

.container{
  padding-top:40vh;
}

label{
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="glass">

        <svg viewbox="0 0 100 25">
            <path fill="#ffeb3b" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z" />
        </svg>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Maybe there is a better solution rather than using SVG to make the shape, but I don't know.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly could one know what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Can you please post an image of what you are after?  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution - add a height to your SVG to make sure it stays as a fixed % of your page and then add a preserveAspectRatio / slice to make sure it doesn't shrink from the 100% width. And adjust the start of the gradient fade so it starts at the bottom of the SVG shape.

I think this is what you want?

```css
body {
        /* Keep the inherited background full size. */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
      padding-left:100px;
      padding-right:100px;
    }

.glass {
        height: 100vh;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        background: inherit;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-grow: 100;
        background: rgb(255,235,59);
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,235,59,1) 0vh, rgba(255,235,59,1) 10vh, rgba(253,216,53,1) 54vh, rgba(249,168,37,1) 100vh);

    }

svg {
        background: white;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 10vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }

.container{
  padding-top:30vh;
}

label{
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="glass">

        <svg viewbox="0 0 100 25" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
            <path fill="#ffeb3b" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z" />
        </svg>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```